# No servidor de produção uso o git como fork ou clone? qual a melhor estrutura para um projeto ativo?

Tags: git, servidor, clone

minha dúvida e sobre qual a melhor forma de usar o git em um servidor de produção.

por exemplo eu tenho um projeto no git mas não sei se é melhor publicar o projeto no servidor via fork via clone, se é bacana manter uma branch exclusiva?

Pensando que eu quero manter atualizações frequentes ao meu projeto de produção e manter sempre atualizado com o git.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de publicar uma aplicação não é pelo Git, e sim por um processo de CI, (Continuous Integration). Na verdade, CI, vai resolver somente o build (compilação), rodar testes, empacotar, etc... e um processo automático de deploy irá fazer a instalação no ambiente para você.

Pode parecer mais complexo, porém, a simples ação de empurrar código para um servidor faz com que surjam alguns problemas:

- **Objetos de referências no repositório de código**: linguagens compiladas costumam ter bibliotecas (libs) como referência, já em nodejs, por exemplo, e esses binários não devem estar no repositório de código, o processo de compilação é responsável por acessá-lo e disponibilizá-los para compilação, e após, empacotar juntamente com o binário gerado.
- **Segredos ou configurações de ambiente**: Senhas de banco de dados e outras chaves, ou mesmo URL's de serviços são diferentes no ambiente de produção em relação ao ambiente de desenvolvimento. Um processo automatizado de deploy irá fazer essa troca.

Enfim, os benefícios são diversos, portanto introduzir um CI traz muitos ganhos ao processo. Existem diversas opções:

- [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)
- [Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), novidade do Github
- [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/?nav=min)
- [Team City](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
- [Go CD](https://www.gocd.org/)